# Capturing signals in C

Tags: c, process, signals

I'm struggling to implement the ability  to capture signals in a process using C language.

Can anyone help-me with a working example?

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried thus far? Have you looked at other minimum working examples available online? If so, what problems have you encountered with them, i.e. are you stuck? Have you read the signal man page?  Here are some resources to get you started:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/catch-signals-sample-c-code/
and: https://gist.github.com/aspyct/3462238

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the `signal.h` library.

Here's a working example in which I capture SIGINT and print a message to STDOUT:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<signal.h>

void sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if (signo == SIGINT)
        write(0, "Hello\n", 6);
}

int main(void)
{
    signal(SIGINT, sig_handler);
    // Just to testing purposes
    while(1)
        sleep(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's working perfectly, thanks! I'm new in programming and in Stack Overflow, thanks for patience

Comment: `printf()` isn't async-signal safe. To directly printf form a a signal handler use `write()`.

Comment: `printf()` is just for showing that I've captured the signal, but, how would you recommend doing it? @alk

Comment: @rafaelcpalmeida: for example `write(0, "Hello\n", 6);`

Comment: I've improved my answer, can you please explain why `write` is async-signal safe whilst `printf` is not? @alk

Comment: Because `write()` does unbuffered I/O, as opposed to `printf()` which uses a buffer. There is also a lot on this topic here on SO.

Comment: Writing to a pipe, and have `main()` read from it and then `printf()` it  would do as well, BTW

Comment: Don't use `signal` interface it is considered as obsolete, prefer `sigaction`.